# Css/Html text box dissapearing text does not work

Tags: java, html, css, textbox, maskedtextbox

I'm making a [website](http://gigster.webege.com). When you click on my search box the text goes away, like it's supposed to, but once you click away the text does not come back and I would like it to. Here is my snippet

```
<div class='search'>
<form method="get" id='search' action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="hidden" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="Site Name:" />
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" style="height: 24px;" value="Search..." onFocus="this.value=''" />
</div>
```

I have alot of css behind it to make the text box enlarge and change color. Here is the code just in case it's relevant.

```
#search input[type="text"] {
background: url(imgs/search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
border: 0 none;
font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
color: #d7d7d7;
width:150px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)   inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
outline: none;
}

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
background: url(imgs/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
color: #6a6f75;
width: 175px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
outline: none;
}
div.search
{
position:fixed;
top:8px;
right:5px;
}
```

When the box is clicked the box enlarges and the `Search...` text goes away like it's supposed to. But once you click away the text does not return and I would like it to. How do I do that? 
*side note 
sorry if website looks bad im 13

Comment: By the way, Java and Javascript are two *very* different languages. You want Javascript, the web language. Java is used to make *real* programs--the kind you run by double-clicking an icon on your desktop. (no offense to web programmers)

Comment: @MathSquared11235 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793773/auto-google-search-results-on-my-website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" style="height: 24px;" value="Search..." onFocus="this.value=''" />
```

for:

```
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" style="height: 24px;" placeholder="Search..." onFocus="this.value=''" />
```

Just need to change value to placeholder :)

Comment: Actually, I'd remove the `onFocus=...` part if I were you. Placeholder does it all.

Comment: i removed onFocus= part . this site has taken me a while im doing it solo i was about to loose my mind if i couldnt get this to work

Comment: hey reel quick since this does a google search how could i make it auto search in say an iframe as you type in the box like as your typing it makes an iframe with search results? how could i do this with ajax? any pointers

Comment: Setup a seperate question on here, its not relevent to the previous question and any other users using this question to help them may become confused :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793773/auto-google-search-results-on-my-website <~ seprate question here

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be compatible with older browsers (ones that do not support html5) you could do something like this:

```
    function removePlaceholder(element)  {
        if (element.value == "Search...") {
            element.value = "";
        }
    }

    function replacePlaceholder(element)  {
        if (element.value == "") {
            element.value = "Search...";
        }
    }
```

And then set your `input` tag to this:

```
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" style="height: 24px;" value="Search..." onBlur = "replacePlaceholder(this)" onFocus="removePlaceholder(this)" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793773/auto-google-search-results-on-my-website is what i need help with i alredy got this to work :) ty tho

Comment: @user1978141 Understood. The only thing is that not all browsers support the placeholder tag, so that is why I answered with that.