# Auto Google Search Results On My Website

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I'm making a [website](http://gigster.webege.com). When you click on my search box and type you click search and then it takes you to google.com with search results how would i use ajax to display results in a frame as you type?.when u search on http://google.com the text you type brings up results by its self without pressing search how can i do this? Here is my html snippet

```
<div class='search'>
<form method="get" id='search' action="http://www.google.com/search">
<input type="hidden" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" value="Site Name:" />
<input type="text" name="q" size="31" maxlength="255" style="height: 24px;" placeholder="Search..." />
</div>
```

I have alot of css behind it to make the text box enlarge and change color. Here is the snippet just in case it's relevant.

```
#search input[type="text"] {
background: url(imgs/search-white.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #444;
border: 0 none;
font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
color: #d7d7d7;
width:150px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)   inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
outline: none;
}

#search input[type="text"]:focus {
background: url(imgs/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
color: #6a6f75;
width: 175px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) inset;
text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
outline: none;
}
div.search
{
position:fixed;
top:8px;
right:5px;
}
```

so how would i make an ajax frame that displays google search results as you type?
i know nothing about ajax i dont know how to start a line of code with it ither so please explain in depth

*side note 
sorry if website looks bad im 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing JavaScript you are pretty well stuck, I recommend learning it first. [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) would be a good place.

Google no longer lets you use their website through an iframe, so I recommend using startpage.com as their results pull from google.com

The simplest way that I can think of to do it is something like this (in this example I use the mobile version of the website as it embeds better.): http://jsfiddle.net/A8M4r/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function querify(query) {
    return query.split(" ").join("+") // replaces spaces with +s for url
}
function updateIframe(query) {
    query = querify(query);
    var i = document.getElementById("searchResults");
    var searchEngine = "http://startpage.com/do/m/mobilesearch/?q=" 
    var yourSiteToSearch= "site:example.com+"
    i.src = searchEngine + yourSiteToSearch + query;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <input oninput="updateIframe(this.value)" type="text">
   <iframe id="searchResults" height="100%" width="100%">
</body>
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. If you would like one where the iframe only pops up when the user clicks on the search box there is one here: jsfiddle.net/4EDUK

Comment: thanks alot i updated it how can i make the iframe show ONLY when the text box is clicked on?

Comment: Oh, and you will probably want to submit your site to google for them to index, it does not look like they have yet. http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

Comment: @user1978141, Just to clarify, the link I gave you does not show the iframe when it is clicked on, but rather when the user enters something in the search box.

Comment: yes i know that how can i hide the frame untill the textbox is clicked? you got me half way to my goal

Comment: @user1978141 Oops! sorry, that was the wrong link. Just a second.

Comment: http://gigster.webege.com/frame.htm ok i edited it now when you type the frame dosent show and my textbox is moved a bit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24255/discussion-between-stephen-and-user1978141)

Comment: i asked a question in chat a min ago

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    var opts = 
    {
       url: "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + $("#mysearchInput").val(),
       success: function(data)
       {
           //parse the results which are in variable "data". 
           //You're going to need to analyze the results yourself
           //and parse it yourself, in whatever way you want to

           var myresults = "my example results here";
           $("#myiframe").append(myresults);
       }
    }

    $.ajax(opts);
});
```

Comment: how can i use this in my code like i said above i have no clue how this works i know html css and php only. where would i put it and what would i have to do to make it work how i want

Comment: See my response to your duplicate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793160/how-to-search-box-auto-search-results/14793216#14793216/. It includes all of the HTML, CSS, jQuery, PHP, etc. you need to do exactly what you described.

Comment: @htmled i am deleteing that question i used the site and still cannot figure it out.

Comment: Without someone writing the code to your site's specific needs, that's as close as you're probably going to get. There's a lot involved in that type of functionality, not just jQuery.

Comment: no exact needs i just want to use my textbox to do the search and display the results in an iframe or iframe like tab.

Comment: You do something like this. You need to add an iframe to your page first in your HTML (though it doesn't have to be an iframe technically, it could just be a div if you want). Give it an ID of "myiframe" or whatever you want. - Then put the example code above in a file called "myscript.js" then in your html head add this line <script type ="text/javascript" src="myscript.js">. You have to modify things in my example such as the example jquery selectors to match your actual selectors, add parsing code for the results that are fetched to make them in a format you want, etc.

Comment: @sajawikio i did that now when my page loads its blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom autocomplete in jQuery you may use one like [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/jQuery) where you would have to define the autocomplete values with an array or remote file.

Else Google Custom Search enables you to use autocomplete through a search box with attribute parameters provided by Google. Here is a webpage that would help you with it - http://www.theblog.ca/autocomplete-google-custom-search-input-field